# meaning of ffmpeg filter option values for modifying contrast/brightness/gamma

Tags: video, ffmpeg, brightness

Context: I am using ffmpeg for processing a raw video file in raw *y4m* format to *mp4* at various brightness values for an experiment looking at OLED display performance. After looking at the ffmpeg documentation I was able to find the following filter (`eq`) for modifying the brightness of the video. 
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq

I used the information from the ffmpeg documentation and the following article (https://wjwoodrow.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/more-ffmpeg-hell/) to get videos with different qualities. But neither the ffmpeg documentation nor the article explains these values in detail.

Question: Now my query is that, what does these `eq` values range correspond to? Is it a percentage? For example,

```
ffmpeg -i input_1080p24.y4m -vf eq=1:-0.5:1:1:1:1:1:1 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 8000k -s 1920x1080 -g 15 -n -r 30 output_1080p.mp4
```

gives me a output video with reduced brightness. But how do I quantify this brightness reduction? Does this `eq = -0.5` correspond to 50% reduction in original brightness? In other words, is this a linear scale?

This is my first post on stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the [source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_eq.c), they look to be linear manipulations of the input values.

Comment: @Mulvya, Thanks! Thats my conclusion so far.